# IIS 7.5 Error 1007

Tags: windows-server-2008, configuration, iis-7.5

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Virtual Server. I removed the *"Default Web Site"* using IIS Manager and now all my other sites now report an error saying they can't access the site (or something similar).

I thought I could just remove the role, re-install IIS again and start with a clean slate.

After I re-installed IIS it's now reporting the following error in the event log:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service
>   (WWW service) failed to register the
>   URL prefix of
>   "http://www.mash-guild.com:80:192.168.245.132/"
>   for the website of "4". The required
>   network connectivity may already be
>   used. The site has been disabled. The
>   data field contains the error number.

This is the full version with the german error note (I'm from germany):

```
Der WWW-Publishingdienst (WWW-Dienst) konnte das URL-Präfix 
"http://www.mash-guild.com:80:192.168.245.132/" für die Website "4" nicht registrieren.
Die erforderliche Netzwerkverbindung wird möglicherweise bereits verwendet. 
Die Website wurde deaktiviert. Das Datenfeld enthält die Fehlernummer. Ereignis-XML:

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"> 
    <System>
          <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC" Guid="{05448E22-93DE-4A7A-BBA5-92E27486A8BE}" EventSourceName="W3SVC" />
          <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1007</EventID>
          <Version>0</Version>
          <Level>2</Level>
          <Task>0</Task>
          <Opcode>0</Opcode>
          <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-03-26T16:14:56.000000000Z" />
          <EventRecordID>1435</EventRecordID>
          <Correlation />
          <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
          <Channel>System</Channel>
          <Computer>WIN-DCJ8SN0QI5J</Computer>
          <Security />
    </System>   
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="UrlPrefix">http://www.mash-guild.com:80:192.168.245.132/</Data>
        <Data Name="SiteID">4</Data>
        <Binary>B7000780</Binary>   
    </EventData> 
</Event>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this or just get back to the IIS + Server settings I had just after I installed windows 2008 ?

Answer (score 1):

Few things --

1. It looks like your other websites are erroring out because something or the other that they are using may be installed into the Default Web Site that you deleted. It is possible these components were being used as subdirectories etc. Please check for this. If this was the case, fixing the other sites will not require restoring the Default Web Site and you should be able to move those folders into other Website applications and remap Urls to make it all work again.
2. To restore your Default Web Site, follow the step by step instructions on this site:

   [How to Recreate Default Website in IIS 7 and above](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-How-to-recreate-e2809cDefault-Web-Sitee2809d-in-IIS-7-75.aspx)

   You will basically need to create a new website and run a adsutil.vbs command to change its ID to "1". And reset IIS.

   Note that after you follow the steps at the above linked article, you will need to manually add the Bindings as per Point #2 (Only Default Website) under "Resolution" at this link:

   [Recreate HTTP and other Bindings on Default Website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2619402)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you open your c:\InetPub\History folder, you may be able to copy an older ApplicationHost.config from that location into System32\Inetsrv\Config.

This location is where the configuration backups are made - a check for changes is performed every 2 minutes, and if it's changed, up to 10 backups are kept. (default settings, configurable)

So if you haven't made more than 10 change sets, there's probably an older copy that might still work, from before you removed the Default Web Site, and this *should* get you back to that, possibly after a service restart.

Comment: it seems that the oldest isnt old enough :(

Comment: Then you'll need to troubleshoot and fix it. Simplest suggestion is to remove the IP address binding and try just the host header (so all IPs, same host header), and see if that gets you any closer.

Comment: yes thats what i was thinking about, can you tell where i find this option to do this?

Comment: Right-click the site, Edit Bindings.

Comment: That error really looks like a Binding Issue to me as well, something else appears to be trying to use that port potentially.